# Can't log into Google Play, gmail, or other apps on new Samsung 7

Tags: troubleshooting

I have changed my Google password in an attempt to be able to log into gmail, Play Store and other apps on my new phone. However, the Play Store app is not recognizing the password change. I cannot get into other apps that I downloaded via the Play Store. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

you should try clear the data of google play store and google play services by going into app settings, if it doesn't work,  you can follow [Google Accounts Help Center](https://support.google.com/accounts/troubleshooter/2402620)